# Value replacement of dataframe - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

One:

```
>df1            a     b     c     d 
     W_1       NA    NA    NA    NA  
     W_2        2     2     2     4   
     W_3        4     2     2     4  
     W_4       NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Second:

```
>df2        a     b        c       d 
    W_1   TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE  
    W_2   FALSE  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE   
    W_3   TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE  
    W_4   FALSE  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
```

I want to replace places in first dataframe with NA, where in second dataframe value is `FALSE`.

The output should be:

```
           a     b     c     d 
W_1       NA    NA    NA    NA  
W_2       NA     2    NA     4   
W_3        4    NA    NA     4  
W_4       NA    NA    NA    NA
```

This is my code:

```
for (i in nrow(df2)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(df2)) {
     a = df2[i,j]
    if (a == FALSE) {
       df1[i,j] = NA
    }
  }
}
```

While I don't get any errors returned, the code doesn't work either. The first dataframe remains unchanged. Any suggestions what may be wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `df1[!df2] <- NA` should do

Comment: Or maybe something like `is.na(df1) <- !df2`

Comment: @quant Compare `FALSE == "FALSE"` and `"FALSE" == "FALSE"`. Coercion saves 'em.

Comment: `df1[!df2] <- NA` and `is.na(df1) <- !df2` returns me an error `Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument type`.

Comment: TRUE/FALSE values are not strings, I tried with 'FALSE' and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

If the rows/cols of `df2` matches exactly the ones of `df1`, you can just use the logical values in `df2` to replace what you want in `df1`:

```
df1[!df2] <- NA
```

@Frank 's way works likewise:

```
is.na(df1) <- !df2
```

**Example:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:16, ncol=4))
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 16, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
df1[!df2] <- NA # or is.na(df1) <- !df2
df1
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  1 NA NA NA
#2 NA  6 10 NA
#3  3 NA NA 15
#4 NA NA 12 NA
```

Comment: It gives me an error `Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument type`, what does it means?

Comment: @bass.bz can you use `dput` to give us the structure of your data, else it is hard to tell what's going on

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with the efficient `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
for(j in seq_along(df1)){
 set(df1, i = which(!df2[[j]]), j=j, value = NA)
 }

df1
#    a  b  c  d
#1: NA NA NA NA
#2: NA  2 NA  4
#3:  4 NA NA  4
#4: NA NA NA NA
```

As @Frank mentioned in the comments, it will also work without converting to `data.table`

```
for(j in seq_along(df1)){
    set(df1, i = which(!df2[[j]]), j=j, value = NA)
  }
df1
#     a  b  c  d
#W_1 NA NA NA NA
#W_2 NA  2 NA  4
#W_3  4 NA NA  4
#W_4 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: It works only when the number of rows is the same in both dataframes?

Comment: @bass.bz  Yes, it was based on your example.  If it is not the same, not sure about the logic you wanted to replace the values